# Nuxt fetch fallback to old api if coming from old route

Tags: nuxt.js

We have upgraded the Nuxt website api to use the slug for the episodes sub-category, whereas the old used the post ID, and want to have a fallback fetch if the user comes to the old link.

The page structure is like this `pages/_slug/_id` and the api calls are the new one: `/show/{_slug}/episode/{_id}` the old one: `/item/{_id}` (they give back the same response)

I tried this kind of structure, but it fails

```
async fetch () {
    this.episodeData = await this.$axios.get(`${baseURL}/show/${this.slug}/episode/${this.id}`)
      .then(res => res.data) 
      .catch((e) => { // if doesn't succed try the old api call
        this.$axios.get(`${baseURL}/item/${this.id}`)
          .then(res => res.data)
          .catch((error) { throw new Error(error) } // the real error handling
      })
```

What could be the correct way to make the fallback call?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what "it fails" means? Does your catch block run? What is the result (error)?

Comment: catch block runs, but it doesn't fetch on SSR from the fallback endpoint. if I make eg. console.log, it is shown on node server, but not on the client. so I believe the nuxt fetch doesn't get back data from that stage